# How did "September" shift from 7th month to 9th month of a year? (and same for October, November, December)

Tags: etymology

If I understand correctly, the words *September, October, November* and *December* all come from French counterpart *Septembre, Octobre, Novembre* and *Decembre*, and ultimately from Latin *septem*, *octo*, *novem* and *decem* with a suffix *-bre*. Therefore I suppose their original meaning were from "**7th** month of a year" to "**10th** month of a year".

Apparently those words stand for "**9th** month" to "**12th** month" nowadays, so why and how did this happen?

Comment: Note that the meaning of the Latin roots is not changed regardless of where September, October, November, and December are in the calendar. While December might be the 12th month of the year, the name "December" does not *mean* "12th month of the year".

Comment: This is not a question about the English language *per se*.

Comment: @Kris it's about word etymology.

Comment: @Ister See answer by Laurel.

Comment: This is still a question about the origins of some English words. Just because the origins happen to predate English doesn't mean it's not a question about English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about history not language usage.

Comment: While I agree that this is actually a facet of history, rather than of language, this is not self-evident (i.e. you don't know that it's not the _words_ that changed until you've read the answer) so it seems fair to ask here.

Comment: The question is rooted in language, but the answer is rooted in History. You can vote to close it if you want, but even in the unlikely case it goes through, it doesn't matter as there's already an accepted answer anyways.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the OED, the switch from month number 7 to 9 was made well before English was even a language:

> The ancient Roman calendar (dating from around the mid 8th cent. b.c.) had ten months; c713 b.c. January and February were added to the end. In 153 b.c. the beginning of the year was moved to 1 January, when the Roman consuls were elected. This new ordering of the months remained when the Julian calendar was introduced in 45 b.c. and in the Gregorian calendar widely used today.

We only use the word "September" in English because it was brought in from Latin.

Comment: So... does that mean "September" actually stands for the 9th month, despite the word "septem" means 7?

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning the commonly accepted - but incorrect - belief that the insertion of Julius and Augustus Caesar's months bumped the 7th-10th months up by two.  Especially as the months that were replaced by July and August were 'Quintillis' and 'Sextillis' with obvious links to their 5th and 6th positions in the previous calendar.

Comment: "... was made well before English was even a language"  -- See my comment at OP.

Comment: Possibly worth explicitly adding that prior to "_the beginning of the year was moved to 1 January_" the beginning of the Roman year _used_ to be **March 1st**, so September _was_ the 7th month, October the 8th and so on. See also [The Roman calendar](https://www.tondering.dk/claus/cal/roman.php), which also confirms that July/August were not _inserted_, just renamed from _Quintilis_ and _Sextilis_.

Comment: @iBug No. September _was_ the 7th month (when the year started in March). The name has been kept although it's "origin" is no longer correct.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Please avoid
discussion or debate
in comments.
The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the
answer,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).